# Chart.js 2.0 (bar chart) reduce x-axis distance between every 2 bar

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, chart.js2

Like the title said, How to reduce the x-axis distance between bar in chart.js 2.0, like the image below.

[image: Example]

Currently, this is my bar

[image]

here is my code

```
.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mx2gh59k/

Answer (score -1):

You can make multiple datasets. One for 2004 and one for 2014.
There is an example code on: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

```
var data = {
labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
        }
    ]
};
```

I've made the same, but i can't post screenshots at the moment.

Comment: You see, the problem is, each bar need to has different color. Using that group "way", the bar color will only have 2 types color

Comment: Why does it have to have different colors?